# Cursor Position Changes When Textbox Size Changed

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the size of a textbox in HTML. Here is my code:

HTML

```
<asp:Label ID="lblEmailBody" runat="server" Text="Content: "></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailBody" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

CSS

```
#txtEmailBody {
    margin-left: 2px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-color: white;
    width:550px;
    height:250px;
}
```

The size changes just like I wanted it to but the cursor position changes to the middle of the textbox. Is there a way to fix this by using HTML and CSS? I looked at some posts on SO about textboxes size and cursor positions but some mention JS and I'm trying to fix this with only HTML and CSS, is this even possible? I want the cursor to be at the left top just like how it would be if you were to write an email. Here is an image of where the cursor is when I click into the textbox.

[image: Cursor Position]

Comment: why dont you use a text area instead?

Comment: @MrJami Could you explain what you mean by text area?

Comment: it is another html tag like a text box but in bigger, good for writing paragraph and so on. This textbox of stack overflow where you just typed a comment is a text area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to create a multi line textbox, right?

Instead of using a textbox/input field, just use a textarea. This is what you need.
You don't need to reconstruct a textbox. You can fix the size of it too if you wish and manipulate it the way you want.

```css
textarea{
height: 300px;
width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<textarea>This is not a textbox but a textarea.</textarea>
```